# When to extends Magento Framework Action

Tags: magento2, class

I have seen a sample module with a class like following.

My question is: 
1) Why do it need to extends `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` since `$context` is not used in execute? 
2) Why `parent::__construct($context)` and not `parent::__construct($context, $session, $order)`

```
class SampleClass extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $order;
    protected $session;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    )
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->order = $order;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // execute code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to extend `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` when you're implementing a **frontend** controller class. It doesn't matter if you are using `$context` or not, you need to extend this abstract class and you'll have to implement `execute` method.
2. `parent::__construct($context)` because this is the constructor signature of `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`. `$session` and `$order` are properties of `SampleClass`.